# UITableViewCell Resizing is not smooth

Tags: ios, objective-c, resize, uicollectionview

I am trying to change `UICollectionViewCell` size depending on a slider's value. Right now, I am managing this by calling `reloadData` on my `UICollectionView` each time my slider has its value changed. The problem is that with big data sources, the refresh is not smooth and sometimes free the application for a little time. Is there any way to enhance this ? I specify that I have images in my cells. Here is the code I wrote :

```
- (IBAction)didChangeCellSize:(UISlider *)sender
{
    [self.collectionView reloadData];
}

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    float size = 120.0 * (self.cellSizeSlider.value + 1);

    return CGSizeMake(size, size);
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ProductCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"productCollectionViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if ((self.filteredProducts == nil && self.products.count > 0  && indexPath.row < self.products.count) || (self.filteredProducts && self.filteredProducts.count > 0  && indexPath.row < self.filteredProducts.count))
    {
        NSDictionary            *product;
        NSData                  *imageData;

        if (self.filteredProducts)
        {
            product = [self.filteredProducts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        }
        else
        {
            product = [self.products objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        }
        imageData = product[ParseDataManagerItemImageData];
        if (imageData)
        {
            UIImage             *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

            if (image)
            {
                cell.productImageView.image = image;
            }
            else
            {
                cell.productImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"DefaultCartItem"];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            cell.productImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"DefaultCartItem"];
        }
        if (self.editMode)
        {
            cell.deleteButton.hidden = NO;
        }
        else
        {
            cell.deleteButton.hidden = YES;
        }
        cell.productNameLabel.text = [product[DataManagerItemTitle] isKindOfClass:[NSString class]] ? product[DataManagerItemTitle] : @"";
        cell.indexPath = indexPath;
        cell.productsVC = self;
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: If image is the problem (remove them and test the response time), try load your images in background instead?

Comment: BTW, I think you can use `setCollectionViewLayout` when resizing.

Comment: Image are definitely the problem. The re-allocation for each cell of the image from the datas takes a long time. So I am now allocating all the images in an array an only assigning it in `cellForItemAtIndexPath`. If you want to write the answer, I will accept it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As confirmed in the question comment, loading image is the cause of the problem.

Allocating an image array first, can solve the problem if `products.count` is *relative* small. Or you will need some kind of 'smarter' cache service running in the background to serve the correct images needed on screen, because I saw you're also using a filter.

Loading the images in a separate thread should help in both cases, so that you can determine whether to load extra files from data or from existing cached versions, maybe an array or other kind, and throw away unused images if your cells can be modified later.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to reload all the cells. Only reload the cells which are visible on screen or currently active. Try this if its work.

```
NSArray *visibleCellIndexPaths = [collectionView indexPathsForVisibleItems];
[collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:visibleCellIndexPaths]
```

Comment: That's not resolving the problem. Thanks anyway.